# Reference to a non-static member should be called

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:

    bool comp(int &a,int &b){
        return a>b;
    }

    int findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        vector<int> vec= nums;
        sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comp);  //error: reference to non-static member should be called

        cout << vec[k-1];
    }
};
```

What is the reason for this error? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you trying doing what the error message says? Did you try making `comp` a `static` member function?

Comment: FYI, `comp` exists in `<functional>` as `std::greater`.

Comment: 1) making `comp` static will fix your error.

2) `std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());` is a cleaner way to write your code

3) Something like 
        `int n = nums.size();
        std::nth_element (nums.begin(), nums.begin()+(n-k), nums.end());
        return nums[n-k];`
will give you better complexity

Comment: There's also no point for the arguments to `comp` to be references, and they absolutely should not be mutable references. Change them to `int`. As someone else said, you can also use `std::greater` instead of your own function. You could also use a lambda: `[](int a, int b) { return a > b; }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing a member function to `std::sort` and since it is a member function you need an instance to invoke it on.

You have a few solutions.

1. Pass a non-member function. This can be just a free function or a static function
2. Use a lambda.

```
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(), [this](int i, int j){return comp(i,j);});
```

3. Use std::bind.

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&Solution::comp, this, _1, _2));
```

4. Use standard library compare function object.

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

5. Use a custom function object

```
 struct {
     bool operator()(int a, int b) const
     {   
         return a > b;
     }   
 } comp;
 .
 .
 sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);
```

P.S:
As others have already pointed out there's no point of using references in `comp` and make sure in your `findKthLargest` function you actually return something.

Comment: `std::function` based solution maybe as well?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, sort function requires a static function return `bool`, but `comp` is a member of `Solution` class (`bool Solution::comp(int&, int&)`).
Easiest way is if you make `comp` a static function

```html
static bool comp(int &a,int &b){
    return a>b;
}
```

Or you can use `std::bind`

Comment: May want to detail how to use `std::bind`

Comment: In c++, std::bind return to a std::function<>. You should `include <functional>` after use std::bind `sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::bind(&Solution::comp, this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2));`

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain std::bind is usually better. Static function is danger if you use many Solution class at the same time

Comment: I thought `std::bind` was generally avoided/replaced by `std::function`? Also I am not sure how calling `comp` many times from many instances creates a problem.